# What weapon, vehicle, or explosive does the most damage?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

There are quite a few ways to damage things in Bad Company 2, but I'm wondering what does the most damage in the game?

While I guess c4 can be piled up to cause a ton of damage at once, I'm only interested in damage per one attack or usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C4 and AT mines with explosive spec equipped (x1.25) do the biggest blast damage - 362.5 points (soldier health is 100 points).

Tank shells with weapon upgrade spec (x1.25) do the most damage to tanks - 1093.75 points (tank health is 1250 points).

I don't know if any spec makes TOW shells stronger, but they do 900 damage to tanks by default (comparing to 875 from tank shells and 865 from C4/AT). So with 1.25 multiplier from a spec it would be the most powerful against tanks - 1125 points.

[[Source](http://denkirson.xanga.com/722757523/bad-company-2/)]

Comment: Do tank shells do a different amount of damage when hitting nontanks?